# Enable port 80 on router apache

Tags: apache, port, router

I have a router on which I am attempting to open port 80 to my pc. I would like to serve a webpage from my pc.

I am following steps from a certain webpage I found: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Ubee/EVW3226---upc/FineCCTV_SR-H2016-N.htm

It is my exact router and it looks quite simpel. However, when I log into my router and fill in

public port range: 80
target IP adress: 
target port range: 80

It gives me an error. Should I fill in something in the target IP adress? I have apache working on port 80 and have set a static IP adress following the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQdxxckMD4I .

When I use that IP adress as target IP adress it does work. However, then I suppose people should be able to go to my IP adress with :80 behind it and get the apache it works page. That doesnt happen.

I am a rookie in all this and this is how far I came. I would like to be able to make some webviewers and send a link to people to show what I made.

Answer (score 0):

You should fill in your server ip address as target ip address of the router.

Try to think from the device you are configuring, you want the data coming from port 80 and direct it to port 80 on your server. So your router has to know where to send id, to which target.

Comment: I want my pc to serve a webpage to anyone filling in my ip adress with :80 behind it. So my own pc is the server. The target should then be my own pc. But how do people not connected to my network get in then?

Answer (score 0):

1) "it gives me an error" is not usefull .... WHICH error, please?

2) You don't tell us which device it is ..... is it exactly the device you have what the document you link is about?

3) In 99% of the cases a home router is listening itsself on port 80 to display the configuration. If you go to http:// a website is displayed. So the router can't forward this port.
You might be able(if programmer of firmware had brain), if you tell the router to use only https for the configuration, then it is listening on port 443 and not longer on port 80. Also there might be an option to disable remote access (from Internet to your router)
sometimes you also have the option to set the port for the configuration yourself. If you change this port to 8080 you can access the router with http://192.168.1.1:8080 (exchange the IP with yours)

Comment: 1. It doesnt give an error. I fill it in, press save, and it just returns to the start log in screen of the router. And it does not save my inputs. 
2. It is exactly the device of the document linked. 
3. I dont have a problem accessing my own router. I want it to open up to people outside of my network. So I dont want to disable remote access but enable.

Comment: 1) and 2) you tried a firmware upgrade?
3)NAT = Network address translation.
Your router has a table with source port, target port, target IP.
Anyone who tries to connect to source port on external IP will become redirected to target IP and target port.